# texture's models imported to Unity don't fit the mesh

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, texture-mapping, uv-mapping

i am trying to import a model into unity, its a creature from Spore that was exported from the game using one of the cheats (i converted it from .dae to .fbx). the textures and all that worked just fine in Blender (consists of a diffuse, normal map, and specular map file all as .tga files)

but upon importing it to Unity and putting the main texture (diffuse) onto the model in the 3D space, it doesn't look right at all. I don't know enough about Unity to know whats going on here, and in general about UV maps and textures... Here are some screen shots-

How it is in blender:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuLQq.jpg

How it is in Unity:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLm7w.jpg

i can attach the model files if needed but i hoped this is likely just a simple fix im not paying attention to. i think it may have to do with how its mapped on the model in blender with nodes (which i can show as well) but am not sure how to change it to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Normal textures may not be set to normal. You can fix it:

[image]

Comment: ah shoot, well i got it fixed by a simple mistake of my own haha... i had two different textures for the character- one for it on four legs. i grabbed the right specular and normal map but it turns out i just grabbed the wrong diffuse file!